# Usar PDO con Sentencias Preparadas también tiene riesgos de inyección SQL?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Me gustaría saber si usando el siguiente ejemplo para realizar consultas SQL también tiene riesgos de inyección SQL:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=***;host=***;charset=utf8mb4', '***', '***');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tabla` (`nombre`, `descripcion`) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$nombre, $descripcion]);
```

Hasta estos momentos la validación que tengo sobre los campos permite todo tipo de caracteres, y se podría enviar esto perfectamente: `'; DROP TABLE tabla`

Lo que me gustaría saber, es si algo como eso tendría efecto y si debo preocuparme. Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo [este post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/are-prepared-statements-100-safe-against-sql-injection5), esta en ingles

Comment: Nada es 100% seguro. Sin embargo, no veo nada por lo que haya que preocuparse en tu consulta. En el código que muestras, colar un `; DROP TABLE tabla` usando `$nombre` o `$descripcion` es imposible. PDO pararía el ataque de inmediato. No entiendo mucho a qué  te refieres cuando hablas de *validación sobre los campos*. Si quieres realmente blindarte en ese sentido, crea una lista de blanca de campos y tablas. Es 99.999999% eficaz ante cualquier ataque.